# Unity3d Errors With transforming position

Tags: c#, error-handling, unity-game-engine, position

My errors are

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float, float, float)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (Assembly-CSharp)
>
> Error CS1503: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Random' to 'float' (CS1503) (Assembly-CSharp)
>
> Error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'ResetBadPos.r' (CS0236) (Assembly-CSharp)

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ResetBadPos : MonoBehaviour {
    Random r = new Random();
    int rInt = r.Next(0, 100); //for ints
    int range = 100;
    // Use this for initialization
    public int points = 0;

    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Bottom Boards") {
            points += 1;
            transform.position = new Vector3(r, -30, 0);
            Score.score += points;
        }
    }
}
```

The errors I have left now after editing are

> Error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'ResetBadPos.r' (CS0236) (Assembly-CSharp)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ResetBadPos : MonoBehaviour {
    Random r = new Random();
    int rInt = r.Next(0, 100); //for ints
    int range = 100;
    // Use this for initialization
    public int points = 0;
    void Start () {
        r = new Random ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }
        void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {

        if (col.gameObject.name == "Bottom Boards") {
            points += 1;
            transform.position = new Vector3(rInt, -30, 0);
            Score.score += points;
        }
    }
}
```

Newest Code and error is now 
 Error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'KillBad.r' (CS0236) (Assembly-CSharp)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class KillBad : MonoBehaviour {
    Random r;
    int rInt = r.Next(-50, 50); //for ints
    int range = 100;
    // Use this for initialization
    public int points = 0;
    void Start () {
        r = new Random ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
        void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {

        if (col.gameObject.name == "Bottom Boards") {
            points += 1;
            transform.position = new Vector3(rInt, -30, 0);
            Score.score += points;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks everybody but now I am having another error
Error CS1061: 'UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for 'Next' and no extension method 'Next' accepting a first argument of type 'UnityEngine.Random' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Assembly-CSharp)

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class KillBad : MonoBehaviour {
    Random r;
    int rInt;

    int range = 100;
    // Use this for initialization
    public int points = 0;
    void Start () {
        r = new Random ();
        rInt = r.Next(-50, 50);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your latest update: At the moment, your code is using the `UnityEngine.Random` [class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html). This one does not have a `Next(int, int)` function, however. It seems like you want to use the .net class `System.Random` which does have a [Next-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Your fix would then be:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class KillBad : MonoBehaviour {
    System.Random r;
    int rInt;

    int range = 100;
    // Use this for initialization
    public int points = 0;
    void Start () {
        r = new System.Random ();
        rInt = r.Next(-50, 50);
}
```

Comment: Thanks now I have another problem in which is changes once but I want it to change every time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want you want to do exactly, but 'rInt' is only updated once since it is in the `Start()` method. In case you want it to change every frame, you can move the line `rInt = r.Next(-50, 50)` to a new method `Update()` which will be called every frame by Unity.

Answer (score 0):

The first two errors will be fixed by changing `transform.position = new Vector3(r, -30, 0);` to `transform.position = new Vector3(rInt, -30, 0);`. This is because you are passing the random object reference as opposed to a random value created by it.

The third error is down to you creating a Random instance inside the field initialiser, so you need to call `r = new Random()` inside the Start method and leave the field declaration as `Random r;`.

Comment: Thanks but I still have one error left in code now that I have updated to show above.

Comment: You didn't make the change I suggested to fix it. You need to change `Random r = new Random();` to just `Random r;`. Then in the Start method you need to put `r = new Random();`.

Comment: Oh that's my fault for not reading the error properly. Change `int rInt = r.Next(0, 100);` to `int rInt;`. Then add `rInt = r.Next(0, 100);` under the Start method.